# MySQL: Warning Invalid (old?) table or database name '#sql2-429-20b'

Tags: mysql, sql, warnings

**[Warning] Invalid (old?) table or database name '#sql2-429-20b'

[Warning] Invalid (old?) table or database name '#sql2-429-213'**

this is being logged to the MySQL error log file when I am try executing a stored proc.
I don't really understand what this means.

The stored proc consists of loop and for each loop there are some records to be created and some updated.

Thats all. proc is very simple
*NB: the table storage engine is INNODB.*

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you running?

Answer (score 0):

If it's possible for you to upgrade to 5.5.22 or higher, I believe this is a fixed bug. See these similar reports:

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=66253
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=62100